# Separating Android.mk file for each flavor

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, android.mk

I’m using Android Studio and Gradle.

There are some flavors that having a little differrent views and features.

So, for each flavor, I want to switch Android.mk1 file.

ex)

- flavorA -> Android_flavorA.mk
- flavorB -> Android_flavorB.mk

but, in externalNativeBuild and ndkBuild block, couldn’t dynamically change a path of Android.mk.

Anybody know about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than having separate makefiles you could pass the product flavor to your makefile:

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                arguments "PRODUCT_FLAVOR=flavor1"
            }
        }
    }
    # etc...
}
```

In `Android.mk`:

```
ifeq (flavor1,$(PRODUCT_FLAVOR))
    # Do flavor-specific stuff
endif
```

I suppose the `Do flavor-specific stuff`-part could be an `include` if your flavor-specific parts are very large.

Comment: Thanks! this is a helpful.

Comment: I am not seeing the make file ran for each flavor though, my arguments never show up and the make file is only ran for each abi